# How to add left/bottom/right panes to Mac application as in XCode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, animation, user-interface, panel

XCode 4 (but also iTunes and other Mac apps) provide side or bottom bars that can be shown or hidden with a smooth animation as the user presses a button.
How can I obtain a similar effect in my applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSSplitView` to do that. You can have more than 2 subviews in a split view (left|center|right) and you can build a kind of hierarchy for the different bars (center consists of top and lower split views).

The show/hide effect is not built in, though. But you should be able to use the `animator` to do that. Most certainly you can also define animations for hiding a view.

You could also use the `BWSplitView` of http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/ where the show/hide animation is already included.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider subclassing `NSViewAnimation`, which I believe Xcode uses in a number of places to achieve its fancy animation effects.